# ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING for chunked transfer encoding for HTTP server

Tags: c, sockets, server, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

My task is to implement simple HTTP server with chunked transfer encoding.
Here is function that read request and send response to the client.

```
 static int serve_request(int sock, struct conf_arg *arg, char version[])
    {
        int html;
        char buf[MAX_MSG];
        const unsigned chunk = (unsigned)CHUNK_SIZE;
        char tempbuf[CHUNK_SIZE + 3];
        ssize_t size;
        ssize_t bytes_read;

        strcpy(buf, arg->root);
        if(buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '/')
            strcat(buf, arg->defdoc);
        html = open(buf, O_RDONLY);
        if (html == -1) {
            perror("Error in opening file");
            not_found(sock, version);
            return -1;
        }
        good_responce(sock, version); 
        size = lseek(html, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek(html, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("SIZE:%d\n", (int)size);
        bytes_read = read(html, buf, size);
        while (bytes_read > chunk) {
            sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (int)chunk);
            write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
            write(sock, buf, chunk);
            write(sock, "\r\n", 2);
            bytes_read -= chunk;
        }
        sprintf(tempbuf, "%x\r\n", (int)bytes_read);
        printf("LAST PART:%d\n", (int)bytes_read);
        write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        write(sock, buf, bytes_read);
        write(sock, "\r\n", 2);
        strcpy(tempbuf, "0\r\n\r\n");
        write(sock, tempbuf, strlen(tempbuf));
        close(html);

        return 0;
    }
```

When I try to open simple site with my server I get error: ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING. So I hope you can help me to find the problem.

Comment: I checked path to file in other function and don't allow to read from other directories.

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned` for something that clearly ought to be `size_t`?!

Comment: also you can use `zd` for `ssize_t`.

Comment: `%x` format conversion requires an `unsigned int`, not a signed `int`. That's probably not your problem, but you should fix it. Also, you send the same (initial) chunk of `buf` on every iteration.

Comment: ... you should probably take a look at what your server is actually sending. You could use a tool like `curl` or even `netcat`.

Comment: `write` is not guaranteed to write all data. It might write less for example if the socket buffer is full. You need to check the return value of `write`.